# what is the source of data in biological database like Genbank

Tags: human-genetics

What is the source of data  in international biological data bases like Genbank and what is it meant for?

Comment: The data sources of GenBank, and the intention of GenBank are stated on their welcome page: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/genbank/

Answer (score 1):

The data comes from scientists who gather data in their labs, such as DNA sequences. It is meant for a number of purposes. First, if science is to repeatable, these data can be checked against other data to see if the conclusions of a paper are valid. They are also used to reduce redundancy in data collection (sequences already exist for a particular species at a particular location, then perhaps further sequencing efforts might be better spent on another species or location). Finally, they can be used as raw data in asking new research questions.